# How to encrypt/hide password in /etc/network/interfaces file on debian?

Tags: debian, networking, password, encryption, wlan

How can I encrypt/hide my - wpa-psk "password" - line in the /etc/network/interfaces file? Since it's uncovered and readable for everyone who can get in the file now.

Or is it better that I use something else if I don't want to store my blank wifi password in a file?

I'm running on debian without desktop environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best you can do is hash the password. Set wpa-psk to the output of:

```
wpa_passphrase <SSID> <KEY>
```

This will obfuscate the password, but it will not prevent someone else from using the hash to connect with another device.

As an additional measure you should also set `/etc/network/interfaces` file permission to `rw-------` (600), `chmod og-rw`.